# Angular: mat-core() and angular-material-theme($my-app-theme); are an undeclared mix-in in theme.scss?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement a custom theme in my Angular project. I have researched for a few hours but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem: mat-core() and angular-material-theme($my-app-theme); are an undeclared mix-in in theme.scss. I tried updating my Angular CLI to the latest version but that didn't work. I am using Angular version 5.2.

Screenshot:
[theme.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3XEA.png)

Comment: Forgot to npm install @angular/material --save ?

Comment: @funkizer - I have Material installed, I'm using the card, inputs, and buttons on my page.

Comment: K. Your theming import is a bit different than in a project of mine where this works, can this be it: @import '~@angular/material/theming';

Comment: Tried that and still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Basically my scss is identical, latest @angular/** versions... weird

Comment: Oh well, when everything else fails, delete node_modules and install again x)

Comment: Can you share package.json file?